# Solving the equation $x^2 + \left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^2 = 15$ using the substitution $u=x+\frac{x}{x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm given equation:
$$x^2 + \left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^2 = 15,$$
and I shall use substitution $u = x + \frac{x}{x-1}$. Where shall I use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$u^2=x^2+\frac{2x^2}{x-1}+\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^2$$

and

$$u=\frac{x^2}{x-1}$$

so

$$u^2=x^2+2u+\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^2$$